# auto populating junction table in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 3 tables in my **Oracle Database 11g**:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  cust_id    NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  cust_name  VARCHAR2(100),
  cust_phone VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Address (
  address_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  address    VARCHAR2(500),
  area       VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer_Address (
  cust_id    NUMBER REFERENCES Customer ( cust_id ),
  Address_id NUMBER REFERENCES Address ( address_id ),
  PRIMARY KEY ( cust_id, address_id )
);
```

Now I want to automate the process of entry of ids into the Customer_Address table checking with the phone no. If the no. exists in the customer table, use the corresponding id else create a new id.

I have tried this by creating a view where I inserted the ids of customer and address tables and then using the **instead of insert trigger** to populate the junction table but it did not work.

This can be done using sequence and trigger? or any other way? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to implement business logic in the database (and indeed you should do so) the proper way to do it is with a stored procedure not a trigger.

```
create or replace procedure insert_address
   ( p_phone_number in customer.cust_phone%type
     , p_address in address.address%type
     , p_area in address.area%type )
is
    l_cust_id customer.cust_id%type;
    l_addr_id address.address_id%type;
begin
    begin
        select c.cust_id 
        into l_cust_id
        from  customer c
        where c.cust_phone = p_cust_phone;
    exception
        when no_data_found then
             insert into customer
             values (customer_id_seq.nextval, 'No name', p_cust_phone) 
             returning cust_id  into l_cust_id;
    end;
    insert into address
    values (address_id_seq.nextval, p_address, p_area) 
    returning address_id  into l_addr_id;
    insert into customer_address
    values (l_cust_id, l_addr_id);
end;
```

Exception handling and other niceties are left as an exercise for the reader.

To be honest this is an artificial exercise: IRL the customer record should exist before the address is gathered. In the scenario the new Customer record doesn't include Customer Name - a rather important attribute. It is also highly unlikely that phone numbers can proxy as UID for customers, even in this age of mobile telephony. In fact, customers are likely to have more than one phone number.

Comment: This is an artificial exercise indeed. The customer record is added with the phone no. If the phone no. does not exist only then a new customer will be added, else the id corresponding to the phone no. will be used to fetch the address. 

I will surely extend my model to include more than one phone no.

Thank you very much for your answer. It will really help me to learn.

Comment: Also another thing I wanted to ask was can I get the parameters from an excel file into this procedure? If there's any way to do it, it'll be great.

Comment: Excel is hard to do from scratch but there are ways. Please ask a new question.